# Complex Equilibrium Points in Dynamical Systems?

Tags: dynamical-systems, systems-of-equations, stability-in-odes

Why do we not study the behavior of a system of ODEs around complex equilibrium points? How does their existence influence the flow?

I have studied the stability and bifurcation analysis for small systems. Perhaps the "[Ghosts](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=JDQGAwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA245&ots=OFLtfsJ2ga&dq=ghost%20bifurcation%20strogatz&pg=PA245#v=onepage&q=ghost%20bifurcation%20strogatz&f=false)" in bifurcation diagrams from Strogatz's book may give some context.

Comment: You've said that you've studied bifurcation analysis. But bifurcation theory *is* the theory that answers what happens first *at* bifurcation point and how you can transform this picture if you perturb the flow. Maybe I've misunderstood your question?

Comment: If you define your dynamical systems to live in real  space (say $R^n$), you cannot talk about complex equilibrium points. On the other hand, in the domain of complex dynamical systems, we do study complex equilibrium points.

Comment: @nonlinearism No-no-no, I think he meant equilibria that can split or disappear after perturbation, i.e. ones with null eigenvalues. I still can't remember the right term for them.

Comment: @nonlinearism I wanted to know why we can't talk about complex equilibria when things like "Ghosts" exist. From what little I understand it seems like complex equilibrium affect the flow for when the equilibrium becomes complex, it vanishes from the picture and yet the phase diagram doesn't change as if it had some latent effect. In brief, if we do talk of complex equilibria for complex valued dynamical systems what information do we miss out when we don't consider them?

Comment: It's not clear what exactly are you asking. What do you mean by "we can't talk about complex equilibria when things like 'Ghosts' exist" ? And phase diagram of course changes. Bottleneck has different effect than equilibrium.

Comment: Could you explain this statement "If you define your dynamical systems to live in real space (say Rn), you cannot talk about complex equilibrium points." Why does it not make sense to talk about them?

Comment: Because complex equilibrium points don't exist in $R^n$, they exist in $C^n$. For defining a dynamical system, you need to first define the phase space. Equilibrium points that don't exist in that phase space cannot be talked about.

Answer (score 3):

Practically speaking, we don't care about the existence of complex equilibrium points because all the realizable models have real signals or states which means that the states can not reach these equilibrium points if they are not real. There are no any kind of complex signals despite of the fact that we represent some concepts in electrical analysis using imaginary number as the reactive power but this still be a representation of a concept that is not a signal or a state of the model.

Also there is a big difference between the existence of the complex eigenvalues of the state matrix and the equilibrium because the eigenvalues are used to analyse the behavior of the dynamical system and they are not values of the states in the system. So, the usage of complex analysis is just to analyze systems.

On the other hand; from the definition of the equilibrium point: it is the point that if the states at that point stay forever, so the states must be complex and this is impossible in practice.